# Refreshing Page After Delete With Ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to refresh the page after I delete a record from the database. I managed to hack the behaviour I want by reloading the windows inside the ajax 'error' but I'm not quite sure why I can't return success to ajax from my controller.

I've tried the following:
Different return types in the controller (RedirectToRoute, RedirectToAction("Index"), Action Result (Return Ok()), plus using POST and GET as the AJAX type (and changing the controller accordingly).

Everything I do (other than reloading inside the error block) deleted the record from the db but never refreshes the page with the new table.

View:

```
@model todo.ViewModels.TodoViewModel

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var t in Model.TodoList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@t.Id</td>
            <td>@t.Name</td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onClick="deleteTodo(@t.Id)" /></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

js:

```
function deleteTodo(i) 
{

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Todo/Delete',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: i
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('fail');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Controller

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var tdlvm = GetAllTodos();
            return View(tdlvm);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public RedirectToActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            using (var connection =
                   new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Todo"))
            {
                using (var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    tableCmd.CommandText = $"DELETE from todo WHERE Id = '{id}'";
                    int rowCount = tableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        internal TodoViewModel GetAllTodos()
        {
            List<Todo> todoList = new();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to redirect from `Controller` which is not really best done using `AJAX`. `AJAX` is used to update a portion of the page and is generally not used to redirect to some other page. In your case you can do the following:

You need to return `Json` from your `Controller` method. You can do that by defining your method to be `JsonResult` which will return `Json` to your `AJAX` call.

You can also use `ActionResult` if there are multiple return types possible deriving from `ActionResult`, like `ViewResult`, `FileResult`, `JsonResult`, etc.

Since you are doing a `GET` action and MVC defaults to `DenyGet` to protect you against a very specific attack involving JSON requests, you need to allow it explicitly. If it were a `POST` action, then you do not need to bother with setting the `JsonRequestBehavior`.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Delete(int id)
{
    int rowCount=0;
    using (var connection =
           new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Todo"))
    {
        using (var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            tableCmd.CommandText = $"DELETE from todo WHERE Id = '{id}'";
            rowCount = tableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    if(rowCount > 0)
    {
      return Json(new {status="true", msg= "Successfully deleted"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
      return Json(new {status="false", msg= "Could not delete"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And you can handle this in your `AJAX` like this:

```
function deleteTodo(i) 
{

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Todo/Delete',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: i
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.status=="true")
          {
            var urlToRedirect= '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
            window.location.href = urlToRedirect; //Redirect here
          }
          else if(data.status=="false")
          {
            alert(data.msg)
          }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('fail');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! What is the purpose of JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet? And what would be the difference between returning "Json" vs "JsonResult"? I'm asking because returning Json seems to work, but obviously I'm interested in best practices :)

Comment: @PabloAguirredeSouza I have updated my answer to include the information regarding your questions. If my answer helped you out, you can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using ajax redirect inside of the controller action is not working. Try this

```
 success: function() {
   alert('success');
   window.location.href= "/home/index";
},
```